# recv with flags MSG_DONTWAIT | MSG_PEEK on TCP socket

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming, linux-kernel

I have a TCP stream connection used to exchange messages. This is inside Linux kernel. The consumer thread keeps processing incoming messages. After consuming one message, I want to check if there are more pending messages; in which case I would process them too. My code to achieve this looks like below. krecv is wrapper for sock_recvmsg(), passing value of flags without modification (krecv from [ksocket kernel](http://ksocket.sourceforge.net/) module)

With MSG_DONTWAIT, I am expecting it should not block, but apparently it blocks. With MSG_PEEK, if there is no data to be read, it should just return zero. Is this understanding correct ? Is there a better way to achieve what I need here ? I am guessing this should be a common requirement as message passing across nodes is used frequently.

```
int recvd = 0;

do {
            recvd   += krecv(*sockp, (uchar*)msg + recvd, sizeof(my_msg) - recvd, 0); 
            printk("recvd = %d / %lu\n", recvd, sizeof(my_msg));
} while(recvd < sizeof(my_msg));
BUG_ON(recvd != sizeof(my_msg));

/* For some reason, below line _blocks_ even with no blocking flags */
recvd = krecv(*sockp, (uchar*)tempbuf, sizeof(tempbuf), MSG_PEEK | MSG_DONTWAIT);
if (recvd) {
            printk("more data waiting to be read");
            more_to_process = true;
} else {
            printk("NO more data waiting to be read");
}
```

Comment: Which one would be appropriate for above case that I mentioned ? I dont want my thread to block if there is nothing on the stream.

Comment: MSG_DONTWAIT should not block.

Answer (score 0):

You might check buffer's length first :

```
int bytesAv = 0;
ioctl(m_Socket,FIONREAD,&bytesAv); //m_Socket is the socket client's fd
```

If there are data in it , then recv with MSG_PEEK should not be blocked ,
If there are no data at all , then no need to MSG_PEEK ,
that might be what you like to do .

Answer (score 0):

This is a very-very old question, but
1. problem persits
2. I faced with it.

At least for me (Ubuntu 19.04 with python 2.7) this MSG_DONTWAIT has no effect, however if I set the timeout to zero (with settimeout function), it works nicely.
This can be done in c with setsockopt function.