# Checking socket buffer without drain it

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I have the following sample using libevent , the epoll library :

```
void read_cb(struct bufferevent *bev, void *arg)
{
    evutil_socket_t fd = bufferevent_getfd(bev);
    struct evbuffer *input = bufferevent_get_input(bev);

    while( 1 ) {
        int datalen = 0 ;
        char buflen[5]={0},record[1024]={0} ;

        size_t len1 = evbuffer_get_length(input);
        if(len1 < 4)
            return ;
        evbuffer_copyout(input, buflen, 4) ;

        try{
            std::string s(buflen) ;
            datalen = stoi(s) ;
        }catch(std::exception const &e){
            std::cout << "error:" << e.what() << std::endl ;
            return ;
        }

        size_t len2 = evbuffer_get_length(input);
        if(len2 < (4+datalen) )
            return ;
        evbuffer_drain(input, 4);
        evbuffer_remove(input,record,datalen) ;
        record[datalen] = 0x00 ;
        console->info("fd ({}) receive ({})",fd,record) ;
        DoOrder(fd,record) ;
    } //while

    return ;
}
```

The client send stream like "0010abcdefghij" , first 4 bytes describe the data part has 10 bytes , so my source check if buffer has 4 bytes in it ?! if so ,
copy 4 bytes out(but not consume it) , check body's length and then check again 
if all header(4 bytes) and body(in my case,it's "abcdefghij") are all in buffer , if so , drain both header and body(in my case, 14 bytes) out of buffer .

I like to do it myself(without using libevent) , I know

```
int bytesAv = 0;
ioctl(m_Socket,FIONREAD,&bytesAv); //m_Socket is the socket client's fd
```

can check bytes count available in buffer(like bufferevent_get_input in my sample) , what I don't know how to implement evbuffer_copyout ,
that means , not only I like to check bytes count available in socket fd's 
buffer , I also like to copy several bytes out of the buffer to check its contents , what function call would do the job ?!

Edit :

[recv with flags MSG_DONTWAIT | MSG_PEEK on TCP socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140802/recv-with-flags-msg-dontwait-msg-peek-on-tcp-socket)

describe MSG_PEEK and MSG_DONTWAIT still make socket blocking , that is not for me since in my case ,  I just like to check buffer contents nonblockingly , blocking won't do the right job to me .

Edit2 :

Using  ioctl(m_Socket,FIONREAD,&bytesAv);  and recv( ...MSG_PEEK) together ,
I should not worry about blocking , since I can always using   FIONREAD to check 
first , then recv with MSG_PEEK won't have blocking problem at all .

Comment: Are you asking how to do it without `libevent`, or how to do it with `libevent`?

Comment: @jxh , libevent source is above , I like to know how to implement the function like libevent evbuffer_copyout do ,  to copy data out of buffer without drain it

Comment: That's what the `MSG_PEEK` flag for `recv()` is for, but I don't see why you think you need it. You just need to loop until you have the four-byte length, then loop until you have data of that length. Peeking doesn't help with that.

Comment: @EJP,  in epoll , I like to have all header(4 bytes) and body(the length described in header) available and then drain it at a time ,  doing a loop is also fine , but  if a client silly do "0010123456789" , header told me there are 10 bytes in body  , but only 9 bytes in body actually , then loop will kill me.

Comment: So you need to debug your client. You can't defend against that; peeking but not drainining the message or non-blocking mode will not help; and you can't use FIO_NREAD as a message length counter. Regardless of what the client does or sends, you may receive as little as a byte at a time. You have to loop.

Comment: @EJP ,  if client A send a wrong data like "0010123456789"  or  I receive data one byte at a time ( like '0','0','1','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0') , epoll will inform me data come in , I can peek if all  14 bytes avaliable , if not , just ignore this fd's event , and deal it until all 14 bytes avaliable in the buffer , I won't do the loop in  read_cb  because  I don't like loop in event's callback function.